# Kafka -> Lambda Event Sink Sending Duplicate Messages

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, apache-kafka-connect

```
class DynamoObject:
    value = {}

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # retreive from sink
    json_object = event
    ct = datetime.datetime.now()
    datetimestr = ct.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S-%f')
    split_string = datetimestr.split(' ')
    date = split_string[0]
    time = split_string[1]
    env = 'sbx'

    folder = 'dashboardCis/' + date + '/'
    filename = time + '.json'

    # S3 try/catch
    try:
        # pass to s3
        print("s3 object: ", json_object)
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        s3.put_object(
            Body=json.dumps(json_object),
            Bucket='...' + env,
            Key=folder + filename
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 500

    #Dynamodb try/catch
    try:
        # parse event
        parsedData = json.dumps(json_object[0]["..."]["..."]["..."])

        # convert to dict/json
        toJson = json.loads(parsedData)


        # convert to dynamodb object
        ...

        # pass to dynamodb
        table.put_item(
            Item = dynamodbObject.value
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 500
    return 200
```

My question pertains to the Kafka -> AWS Lambda sink connector. Our connector works just fine, but when the topic messages are produced in Kafka, it's producing multiple messages to the AWS environment through the sink. Is there a way to limit these messages to 1 so we don't get duplicates sent to S3 and Dynamo?

[image: Cloudwatch]

Comment: Are the offsets of the Kafka messages duplicated as well? Is that part of your dynamo object? If not, they are not true "duplicates". More specifically, a sink connector should read a message, and commit that offset, and not seek backwards or re-send the event... You'll need to look at the logs of the connector to see if that is happening

Comment: How many messages are duplicated, a small number or a very large number? What is the value of `enable.auto.commit` in your consumers? By default it's true which means that Kafka guarantees that each message is processed [at least once](https://medium.com/@andy.bryant/processing-guarantees-in-kafka-12dd2e30be0e), so your application must handle duplicates.

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes. The offsets are duplicated as well. So the duplicates are happening at the offset level as well. The same message comes into the topic 12+ times for each change.

Comment: @Yos a very large number, so far anywhere from 12 to 30+ times it gets duplicated.

Comment: Then, if the producer isn't sending duplicate data (since offsets are the  same), then sounds like your Connect worker is either rebalancing or otherwise has very inconsistent connection to the broker to commit back events it's already consumed